# how to set up feed with aws s3 and chocolatey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chocolatey

I am trying to set up a chocolatey packet gallery where the repository is an AWS  S3 bucket. I installed and configured the packet gallery, but now I do not know to set the repository to S3

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to find a NuGet repository offering that can use S3 buckets as a data store, or find a way to bring that bucket as a mirror to a physical machine that you can easily hook up to almost any of the NuGet package repository offerings that are out there. See https://chocolatey.org/docs/how-to-host-feed for some options.